# jQuery - Hook function to html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to hook a function to an html attribute?

For example:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="ajax.php" id="login-form" data-function="doSomething">
     //...
</form>
```

JS:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('hello!');
}

$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result){
            form.attr('data-function'); //<-- call the function defined in data-function here
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this if you store the function in an object

```
const obj = {
    doSomething() {
        alert('hello!');
    }
}
```

then you can call doSomething with

```
obj['doSomething']()
```

Comment: Ah I see, that'll do. Thanks!